# Git subtree error

Tags: git, macos, osx-lion, git-subtree

I tried to install [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) on Mac and after the first step:

```
cp git-subtree.sh "$(git --exec-path)"/git-subtree
```

when I try to use git-subtree I get always an error:

```
sudo git subtree split -P ObjectiveBlip export 
fatal: cannot exec 'git-subtree': Operation not permitted
```

My git version is 1.7.7.4.

Comment: Did you make the `git-subtree.sh` script executable?  i.e. does it work after doing `chmod a+rx "$(git --exec-path)"/git-subtree` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I did that but the problem was other. I fixed it xattr -d com.apple.quarantine git-subtree.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you solved the problem.  You should add that as an answer to your own question, since it may well be useful to other people.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem with `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine git-subtree`.